# How to resolve a service by implementation type?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's say I have the following setup:

```
interface IDoSomething { }

class Something : IDoSomething { }

class AnotherThing : IDoSomething { }
```

I register the classes with the built-in DI container like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDoSomething, Something>();
services.AddTransient<IDoSomething, AnotherThing>();
```

I have no problem resolving both of these by injecting IEnumerable<IDoSomething>. But, I need a way to resolve a specific one by the implementation type.  Something like:

```
var x = serviceProvider.GetService<Something>();
```

*(where serviceProvider is IServiceProvider)*

However, this always returns null.

If I add the following registration, this works fine:

```
services.AddTransient<Something>();
```

**Is there a way to resolve a dependency by the implementation type without having to register the type twice (once so I can resolve by the interface and the other so I can resolve by the implementation type)?**

Comment: you should resolve service using var x = serviceProvider.GetService<IDoSomething>();

Comment: Actually, you should never even do that since ServiceLocator is actually an anti-pattern. But, that isn't the question.  For this project, the need to is resolve the specific implementation based on a set of rules that I didn't include for brevity.

Comment: To resolve a type by concrete implementation, you need to register that. You have only registered the interface in your examples above. So no, you can't with the built-in DI. You could however use a 3rd party IoC/DI container one which behaves differently